# What difference does anyExchange().authenticated() really make?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

What difference does `anyExchange().authenticated()` really make? Consider this MRE:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>security-mre</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>security-mre</name>
    <description>security-mre</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
package com.example.securitymre.controller;

import com.example.securitymre.data.Hello;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Hello getHello() {
        return new Hello();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.securitymre.data;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Hello {
    private final String message = "Hello!";
}
```

I hardly wrote any code, no security config, and yet

```
curl -i localhost:8080/hello
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
content-length: 0
```

**I'm already barred from using my application unauthenticated**

Experiment #2

```java
package com.example.securitymre.data;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Hello {
    private String message = "Hello!";

    public Hello(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.securitymre.controller;

import com.example.securitymre.data.Hello;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Hello getHello() {
        return new Hello();
    }
    @GetMapping("/secured-hello")
    public Hello getSecuredHello() {
        return new Hello("Secured hello!");
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.securitymre.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity security) {
        return security
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> authorizeExchangeSpec
                        .pathMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()/* by "any" we mean GET /secured-hello */.authenticated()
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
curl -i localhost:8080/hello                                                         
HTTP/1.1 200 OK                                                                                     
Content-Type: application/json                                                                      
Content-Length: 20                                                                                  
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate                                       
Pragma: no-cache                                                                                    
Expires: 0                                                                                          
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff                                                                     
X-Frame-Options: DENY                                                                               
X-XSS-Protection: 0                                                                                 
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer                                                                                                                                                                            
{"message":"Hello!"}
                                                                                
curl -i localhost:8080/secured-hello                                                 
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized                                                                           
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"                                                               
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate                                       
Pragma: no-cache                                                                                    
Expires: 0                                                                                          
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff                                                                     
X-Frame-Options: DENY                                                                               
X-XSS-Protection: 0                                                                                 
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer                                                                        
content-length: 0
```

Or without `anyExchange().authenticated()`:

```java
package com.example.securitymre.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity security) {
        return security
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> authorizeExchangeSpec
                        .pathMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
curl -i localhost:8080/hello                                                         
HTTP/1.1 200 OK                                                                                     
Content-Type: application/json                                                                      
Content-Length: 20                                                                                  
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate                                       
Pragma: no-cache                                                                                    
Expires: 0                                                                                          
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff                                                                     
X-Frame-Options: DENY                                                                               
X-XSS-Protection: 0                                                                                 
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer                                                                                                                                                                            
{"message":"Hello!"}  
                                                                              
curl -i localhost:8080/secured-hello                                                 
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized                                                                           
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"                                                               
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate                                       
Pragma: no-cache                                                                                    
Expires: 0                                                                                          
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff                                                                     
X-Frame-Options: DENY                                                                               
X-XSS-Protection: 0                                                                                 
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer                                                                        
content-length: 0
```

Literally, zero difference

I don't claim to have a lot of experience, but in each project I worked on, had that `anyRequest().authenticated()` line. Now it appears it's some default, and it doesn't have any practical purpose

Am I missing something? What does that line do, exactly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TLDR: It doesn't do anything since it's called for you anyway

`ServerHttpSecurity` is basically a container for configuration properties that are then used to build  a `WebFilter` (or more specifically, to create a `SecurityWebFilterChain` which is then wrapped in a `WebFilterChainProxy` object which is a `WebFilter` subtype). `ServerHttpSecurity` has a bunch of nested classes that encapsulate certain aspects of that configuration. One of them is `AuthorizeExchangeSpec` whose purpose in life is to supply an `AuthorizationManager` to `AuthorizationFilter`'s constructor, call it, and add the filter instance to `ServerHttpSecurity` (the outer class) as an authorization filter. Here's the code that does it:

```java
// ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec

        protected void configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
            Assert.state(this.matcher == null,
                    () -> "The matcher " + this.matcher + " does not have an access rule defined");
            ReactiveAuthorizationManager<ServerWebExchange> manager = this.managerBldr.build();
            ObservationRegistry registry = getBeanOrDefault(ObservationRegistry.class, ObservationRegistry.NOOP);
            if (!registry.isNoop()) {
                manager = new ObservationReactiveAuthorizationManager<>(registry, manager);
            }
            AuthorizationWebFilter result = new AuthorizationWebFilter(manager);
            http.addFilterAt(result, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);
        }
```

That manager is treated a bit like a map. When you call all those `pathMatchers().hasAnyRole()`, `anyExchange().authenticated()`, etc., you're basically putting key-value pairs into that `AuthenticationManager` (or rather, its builder). The "keys" are `ServerWebExchangeMatcher`s which are nothing but glorified `Predicate<ServerWebExchange>` (in effect). That `anyExchange()` call is for all intents and purposes equivalent to `serverWebExchange -> true`

```java
// ServerWebExchangeMatchers

/*
 maybe I'm stupid, but aren't this anonymous subclass's equals() and hashcode() 
exactly the same as if it was a lambda, i.e. this == o?
*/

    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Lambda")
    public static ServerWebExchangeMatcher anyExchange() {
        // we don't use a lambda to ensure a unique equals and hashcode
        // which otherwise can cause problems with adding multiple entries to an ordered
        // LinkedHashMap
        return new ServerWebExchangeMatcher() {

            @Override
            public Mono<MatchResult> matches(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
                return ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match();
            }

        };
    }
```

The "values" are `ReactiveAuthorizationManager`s (yes, the big authorization manager that we construct is sort of made up of tiny authorization managers inside) which are effectively `Predicate<Authentication>`

```java
public class AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager<T> implements ReactiveAuthorizationManager<T> {

    private AuthenticationTrustResolver authTrustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager() {
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<AuthorizationDecision> check(Mono<Authentication> authentication, T object) {
        return authentication.filter(this::isNotAnonymous)
            .map(this::getAuthorizationDecision)
            .defaultIfEmpty(new AuthorizationDecision(false));
    }

    private AuthorizationDecision getAuthorizationDecision(Authentication authentication) {
        return new AuthorizationDecision(authentication.isAuthenticated());
    }
```

```java
public class AuthorizationDecision {

    private final boolean granted;

    public AuthorizationDecision(boolean granted) {
        this.granted = granted;
    }

    public boolean isGranted() {
        return this.granted;
    }
```

So when `anyExchange().authenticated()` is invoked, the following method is invoked with `AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager.authenticated()` as its argument. Basically, it adds a key-value pair that says, "Whatever the request, greenlight it only if its authentication `isAuthenticated()`". By the way, I could trick that authorization filter by simply registering another filter bean that simply toggles that flag

```java
// ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec

    public AuthorizeExchangeSpec authenticated() {
        return access(AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager.authenticated());
    }
```

```java
// ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec

            public AuthorizeExchangeSpec access(ReactiveAuthorizationManager<AuthorizationContext> manager) {
                AuthorizeExchangeSpec.this.managerBldr
                    .add(new ServerWebExchangeMatcherEntry<>(AuthorizeExchangeSpec.this.matcher, manager));
                AuthorizeExchangeSpec.this.matcher = null;
                return AuthorizeExchangeSpec.this;
            }
```

Now, why is the behavior the same even without any explicit configuration at all?

First, there's an out-of-the-box configuration called `WebFluxSecurityConfiguration` that supplies a `WebFliterChainProxy` built from a default `ServerHttpSecurity`. Here it is. Notice it doesn't call `authorizeExchange()` which means `authorizeExchange` stays `null` (I checked it with the debugger)

```java
// ServerHttpSecurityConfiguration

/* 
By the way, do you know that this bean's name is "org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity"
even though it's declared in a **Server**HttpSecurityConfiguration? I guess it's due to a copy-paste from the old HttpSecurity
*/

    @Bean(HTTPSECURITY_BEAN_NAME)
    @Scope("prototype")
    ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity() {
        ContextAwareServerHttpSecurity http = new ContextAwareServerHttpSecurity();
        // @formatter:off
        return http.authenticationManager(authenticationManager())
            .headers().and()
            .logout().and();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

```java
// ServerHttpSecurity

    @Deprecated(since = "6.1", forRemoval = true)
    public AuthorizeExchangeSpec authorizeExchange() {
        if (this.authorizeExchange == null) {
            this.authorizeExchange = new AuthorizeExchangeSpec();
        }
        return this.authorizeExchange;
    }
```

```java
// ServerHttpSecurity

    public ServerHttpSecurity authorizeExchange(Customizer<AuthorizeExchangeSpec> authorizeExchangeCustomizer) {
        if (this.authorizeExchange == null) {
            this.authorizeExchange = new AuthorizeExchangeSpec();
        }
        authorizeExchangeCustomizer.customize(this.authorizeExchange);
        return this;
    }
```

Second, when they *do* retrieve that bean from the context, they *keep configuring it* which includes calling those exact methods, `anyRequest().authenticated()`

*The fact that they retrieve a bean from the context (which should be completely initialized by that point) and still keep configuring it, spreading defaults all over the codebase instead of keeping them in one place makes me unhappy*

```java
    @Bean(SPRING_SECURITY_WEBFILTERCHAINFILTER_BEAN_NAME)
    @Order(WEB_FILTER_CHAIN_FILTER_ORDER)
    WebFilterChainProxy springSecurityWebFilterChainFilter() {
        WebFilterChainProxy proxy = new WebFilterChainProxy(getSecurityWebFilterChains());
        if (!this.observationRegistry.isNoop()) {
            proxy.setFilterChainDecorator(new ObservationWebFilterChainDecorator(this.observationRegistry));
        }
        return proxy;
    }

    @Bean(name = AbstractView.REQUEST_DATA_VALUE_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
    CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor requestDataValueProcessor() {
        return new CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    static BeanFactoryPostProcessor conversionServicePostProcessor() {
        return new RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor();
    }

    private List<SecurityWebFilterChain> getSecurityWebFilterChains() {
        List<SecurityWebFilterChain> result = this.securityWebFilterChains;
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
            return Arrays.asList(springSecurityFilterChain());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain() {
        ServerHttpSecurity http = this.context.getBean(ServerHttpSecurity.class); // get default ServerHttpSecurity bean...
        return springSecurityFilterChain(http);
    }

    /**
     * The default {@link ServerHttpSecurity} configuration.
     * @param http
     * @return
     */
    private SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated(); // ...and keep configuring it! Wtf is this?
        if (isOAuth2Present && OAuth2ClasspathGuard.shouldConfigure(this.context)) {
            OAuth2ClasspathGuard.configure(this.context, http);
        }
        else {
            http.httpBasic();
            http.formLogin();
        }
        SecurityWebFilterChain result = http.build();
        return result;
    }
```

I could mention `WebHttpHandlerBuilder` (which asked the context for all `WebFilter` beans, including our `WebFilterChainProxy`), `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` (which put the bean definition of that default `ServerHttpSecurity` to the context's bean factory in the first place), but I guess that would be too much of a diversion

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/configuration/webflux.html) about it.

You will be able to understand that `anyExchange().authenticated()` usually mean that every request to any endpoint of application should be authenticated. In the other hand if you not specify this one, It would work in this way by default as you have in your second configuration it is the reason why you do not see any difference.

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is not specific enough. For example, you can reference specific inlines that precisely match the effect of `anyRequest().authenticated()`

Comment: Also, if you don't enjoy helping people, if it annoys you (you sound annoyed in your answer), simply don't do it. It is not your obligation

Comment: Hey, I enjoy doing it and I don’t see any annoying things in my answer. I just gave you the reference to docs and a short answer to the question.

Comment: Another good reference to understand more deep [Authorize ServerHttpRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html)

Comment: Check out my answer. *That's* what I expected

Comment: @JoreJoh i think your expectations of volunteers is a bit high. Astronomical even.

Comment: @KevinB they are exactly as high as SO's expectations from questions themselves